# copy cell value to another column but if there is different value by same searching criteria put in the same row

Tags: excel, vba

So I need simple vba script. I have 3 columns. I need to find each value from column C in Column A and offset value from column B right next to value from column C.

For this I can use VlookUp, I know.
But If there is more than one same value in Column A with different offset value from B, I need to put those all different values in the same row, right next to C column value.

thanks guys in advice

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this kind of code but it works just with first match skipping others...

P.S. I changed columns

```
Sub Sample()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim DataRange As Range, UpdateRange As Range, aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    On Error GoTo Err

    Set ws = Worksheets("Missing_Subnets_21048_COPY")
    Set UpdateRange = ws.Range("K6:K12")
    Set DataRange = ws.Range("H6:H12")

    For Each aCell In UpdateRange
        Set bCell = DataRange.Find(What:=aCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)


        If Not bCell Is Nothing Then
           aCell.Offset(, 1) = bCell.Offset(, 1)
        End If
    Next

    Exit Sub

Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: changed columns for testing